# telebot delete all bot's messages in chat

Tags: message, telebot

I suppose, first we need to get all messages id's.
I know how to get id of the message bot just sent.
Like that:

`msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess, reply_markup=menu) id = msg.message_id`

and then delete it

`bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, id)`

But how to find id's of the messages bot has sent before, and then delete those messages?